# Combining duplicate dataframe rows with concatenating values for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to combine rows in a way where I concatenate values for a specific column but get some unexpected result on my own dataset. Here is an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1', '2', '3', '1', '3', '4', '4', '6', '6'],
                'words':['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a' ]})
df2 = df.groupby('id')['words'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

df2.head()
```

The result looks like this which is what I want and is fine.

```
    id  words
0   1   a b
1   2   b
2   3   c a
3   4   a b
4   6   c a
```

Unique values based on words column and again it looks fine:

```
df2.words.value_counts()
c a    2
a b    2
b      1
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

However, in my own dataset which is big (can't really reproduce it here), the output of `df2.words.value_counts()` produces something like this and I can't figure it out why. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

```
df2.words.value_counts()
c a    10
a c    5
a b    10
b a    5
b      1
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

But it should be as follows:

```
df2.words.value_counts()
c a    15
a b    10
b      1
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

The values here are fake but I get the same values for 'words' column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion simpliest is sorting values in `join` function, so `value_counts` working correct:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id')['words'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x))).reset_index()
print (df2)
  id words
0  1   a b
1  2     b
2  3   a c
3  4   a b
4  6   a c

print (df2.words.value_counts())
a b    2
a c    2
b      1
Name: words, dtype: int64
```